# Cancel Button appears Disable on iOS 5 when using presentViewController

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller, uinavigationitem

on iOS 4 i am using the following line of code to get the PhotoLibrary and its working perfect and the view can be dismissed with the cancel button appearing on top right side:

```
[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
```

However, on iOS 5 the following line is getting the PhotoLibrary but the "Cancel Button" is Disable, i.e. the view cannot be dismissed with cancel button.

```
[self  presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];            
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];                
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:TRUE];
```

This works fine for me, in iOS 5, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a view controller, but a view controller class. Try using your old `imgPicker` rather than the `UIImagePickerController`.

Also, there is no such thing as `Nil` in objective C. It should be `nil`.

Comment: imgPicker is UIImagePickerController and it is working fine with iOS 4 , any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Replace the `UIImagePickerController` with the instantiated `imgPicker`.